# Write SQL output from IBM i Db2 to IFS in XML format using QSYS2.IFS_WRITE

Tags: sql, xml, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am attempting to write XML output from a Db2 file to the IFS.

Running this SQL statement from System i Navigator SQL gives me the proper output on the navigator window:

```
select xmlelement (name "root",  
    xmlelement (name "EmployeeList",
      XMLAGG (
        XMLELEMENT (NAME "Employee",
          XMLFOREST (
            trim(id) as "ID",
            trim(firstname) as "FirstName",
            trim(lastname) as "LastName"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
FROM myfile;
```

Below line feeds and spacing added for clarity:

```
<root>
 <EmployeeList>
  <Employee>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <FirstName>ROBERT</FirstName>
   <LastName>JONES</LastName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
   <ID>2</ID>
   <FirstName>SMITH</FirstName>
   <LastName>FRED</LastName>
  </Employee>
 </EmployeeList>
</root>
```

I have no problem writing to the IFS if I use constants like this:

```
CALL QSYS2.IFS_WRITE(
  PATH_NAME =>'/myFileInXML.xml',
  OVERWRITE => 'REPLACE',
  FILE_CCSID => 1208,
  LINE => ('<root><EmployeeList><Employee><ID>99</ID><FirstName>Joe</FirstName><LastName>Arbuckle</LastName></Employee></EmployeeList></root>'
 )
);
```

However, if I combine the select with the IFS write like this, I get an error my argument is not valid:

```
CALL QSYS2.IFS_WRITE(
  PATH_NAME =>'/myFileInXML2.xml',
  OVERWRITE => 'REPLACE',
  FILE_CCSID => 1208,
  LINE => (

select xmlelement (name "root",  
    xmlelement (name "EmployeeList",
      XMLAGG (
        XMLELEMENT (NAME "Employee",
          XMLFOREST (
            trim(id) as "ID",
            trim(firstname) as "FirstName",
            trim(lastname) as "LastName"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
FROM myfile

 )
);
```

> SQL State: 07006 Vendor Code: -301 Message: [SQL0301] Input variable
> *N or argument 4 not valid. Cause . . . . . :   The value in relative position 4 in the statement is a type that is not compatible with the
> requested operation. The value is variable *N, entry 4 in a descriptor
> area, or argument *N in a CALL statement.  A name *N indicates that a
> user's descriptor area was used or that a constant or special register
> was specified on the CALL statement. Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the
> following and try the request again: -- Use a variable that is the
> correct type. -- Specify an argument in the CALL that is the correct
> type. -- Change the type specified for parameter 4 in the DECLARE
> PROCEDURE statement.

Advice would be appreciated on how to create a stream file on IFS from Db2 output in XML format.

Edit - also tried this technique:

```
create table myfilexml (info xml);

insert into myfilexml
select xmlelement (name "root",  
    xmlelement (name "EmployeeList",
      XMLAGG (
        XMLELEMENT (NAME "Employee",
          XMLFOREST (
            trim(id) as "ID",
            trim(firstname) as "FirstName",
            trim(lastname) as "LastName"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
FROM myfile;
```

Problem here it it only works if there is only one record in the file. The error here is:

> SQL State: 2200L Vendor Code: -20345 Message: [SQ20345] XML value not
> a well-formed document. Cause . . . . . :   The XML value is not a
> well-formed document.  An XML value that is being stored in a table
> must be a well-formed XML document with a single root element.
> Recovery  . . . :   Change the XML value to be a well-formed document
> with a single root element.  Try the request again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `xmlserialize` function to convert the `XMLELEMENT` to a `CLOB`.

Here is a query which writes the contents of a source member to a stream file in XML format:

```
call  qsys2.ifs_write( path_name=>'/home/steve/xml.txt',    
   overwrite=>'REPLACE', file_ccsid=>1208, line=>  (           
select xmlserialize(xmlelement (name "root",                   
    xmlelement (name "srcmbr",                                 
      XMLAGG (                                                 
        XMLELEMENT (NAME "srcline",                            
          XMLFOREST (                                          
            trim(srcseq) as "srcseq",                          
            trim(srcdat) as "srcdat",                          
            trim(srcdta) as "srcdta"                           
        ))))                                                   
)  as clob(50k)) srccode                                       
FROM qrpglesrc    ))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast turnaround. This helped tremendously. Reading up on xmlserialize right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the xml document into a variable and then write it into the file

Which looks like

> ```
> CREATE tABLE myfile(ID int, FirstName varchar(20),LastName  varchar(20))
> ```

> ```
>   EXEC SQL select xmlelement (name "root",  
>     xmlelement (name "EmployeeList",
>       XMLAGG (
>         XMLELEMENT (NAME "Employee",
>           XMLFOREST (
>             trim(id) as "ID",
>             trim(firstname) as "FirstName",
>             trim(lastname) as "LastName"
>         )
>       )
>     )
>   )
> )
> INTO :xml_doc
> FROM myfile;
> CALL QSYS2.IFS_WRITE(
>   PATH_NAME =>'/myFileInXML.xml',
>   OVERWRITE => 'REPLACE',
>   FILE_CCSID => 1208,
>   LINE => (:xmo__doc
>  )
> );
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=03e6b63dd24d0c17c898adab0b8e1a37)*

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Reading up on xmo__doc and xml_doc right now.